# Is it possible to save MacOS application user guides for offline reading?

Tags: macos, automator

I was working with Automator offline and wanted to look up something on the userguide but I learned it cannot be accessed offline? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/automator/welcome/2.9/mac/10.14.5

This is the homepage of the web version of the guide (for my Mac). For your Mac, use open in Safari in Share menu that sits beside table of contents in menu bar of help guide.  You can either

- print it page by page in browser or in the Help guide.
- or use some tools like wget (recursive <sup>1</sup>) or curl (single shot<sup>1</sup>) to download all pages.
- or save the page in web archive or page source whichever suitable, using File -> Save as (<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> )

<sup>1: https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another "method":
On the webpage that shows the guide/manual in Safari: 
Safari menu->View->select "Show Reader", another format is shown (bookformat).
Now Safari menu->File->export as PDF.

Comment: CMD + Shift +  R being the shortcut. I personally prefer it..

Comment: Show reader is disabled on the guides for me.