# Using wget: offline official apple user guides

Tags: macos, ventura

I came from this question because I wanted to do something similar: [Reviewed Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371297/is-it-possible-to-save-macos-application-user-guides-for-offline-reading)

I've just installed the 'wget' command line tool through home-brew.

I would like to create an offline copy of the following official apple user guide: [iMovie User Guide](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/imovie/welcome/mac)

I'm using the following command:

```
wget —mirror —page-requisites —convert-link —no-clobber —no-parent  https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/imovie/welcome/mac
```

Nevertheless, the only result I seem to be obtaining is an unopenable file named 'mac' with no extensions.

Where am I going wrong? Do I need different flag configurations?

Comment: Have you tried adding .html to the file, or opening it in a text editor?

Comment: Interesting, that way it does indeed become readable...

Comment: Apps will only open documents with file extensions that they recognise. Otherwise, it's just a "random file", and Safari doesn't know it's an HTML file.

Comment: Have you tried the `-O` (letter “O” not zero) option?  For instance, use `-O foobar.html` to give it a correct filename and extension.

Answer (score 2):

The following **official documentation** proved very useful: [gnu Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/)

This is the command that did the job:

```
wget -r -l 2 -np -k -E -p https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/imovie/
```

Notes: (personal observations, please check **official documentation** for precise and up-to-date info)

wget: cmd invoked

-r: recursion (I wanted any page contained in '/imovie/' to be downloaded: eg. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/imovie/**mov142f39686/mac**)

-l 2: level; the specified 'level' of recursion (subfolder depth): I set this as 2, because that was the 'deepest' (relative to '/imovie') webpage type I could find, eg: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/*imovie*/**move8b2e15e3**/**mac** ; https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/*imovie*/**mov4d3dce7ba**/**mac**

-np: no parent; wanted to stay in the '/imovie' "directory", and didn't want to ascend to its 'parent' (parent in bold: /**guide**/imovie/) or beyond:

-k: convert links; made sure the links in the offline version pointed to (offline) system directories rather than their online counterparts.

-E: adjust extension; made sure all files were '.html' so they were openable (thanks for @benwiggy's suggestion:

> Have you tried adding .html to the file, or opening it in a text editor? –
> benwiggy
> 21 hours ago

-p: page requisites; made sure supplementary web page features such as images were downloaded and visible in offline version

-also notice I gave wget the URL up to '/imovie', and not the complete URL you would usually see if you open the documentation:
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/imovie/welcome/mac

this was because all the pages I wanted to download were contained in '/imovie'.

Comment: The first line "official documentation proved very useful" deserves an up vote all on it's own.  Welcome to Ask Different!  Glad you found a solution!